# What's wrong with my code?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, null

There is a null error, and i've been trying to solve it for 2 days.

Booking.java

```
package one.two;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


public class Booking extends Activity
{
    private DBAdapter db; 
    private Spinner colourSpinner;
    public Cursor myCursor;
    public TextView txtArrival;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.booking);
        txtArrival = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArrival); // Member assignment
        colourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.myspinner); // Member assignment
        db.open();
        fillData();
        db.close();
        colourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    private void fillData()
    {
        myCursor = db.getSpinnerData();
        startManagingCursor(myCursor);
        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_ARRIVAL};
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.booking, myCursor, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        // Removed this line, since members is set in onCreate
        colourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id)
        {
            boolean result = Booking.this.myCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            if (result) {
                String title=Booking.this.myCursor.getString(1);
                Booking.this.txtArrival.setText(title);
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
}
```

LogCat

```
08-10 03:45:06.467: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at one.two.Booking$MyOnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(Booking.java:54)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:856)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:41)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:827)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
08-10 03:45:06.567: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(750):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, i am supposed to put data from database into the textview.

Comment: Booking.this?  Seems very odd syntax; am I missing something?

Comment: @Alison that is how to get a reference to the outer class from an inner class.

Comment: @codinguser thanks, I obviously don't use inner classes enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 54 (if SO preserved all formatting correctly) is `Booking.this.txtArrival.setText(title);` which means `txtArrival` is probably null. It should have been initialized in your onCreate, but it clearly hasn't. If you check the documentation for `View#findViewById`, you'll see that it returns "[t]he view if found or null otherwise."

I'd wager that the view with id `txtArrival` is not present in your booking.xml layout file.

Comment: <TextView
     android:text="@+id/txtArrival"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    />

Comment: Hmm, I see now. There's an error in your XML. It should be android:id instead of android:text.

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at your code either

```
boolean result = Booking.this.myCursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

or

```
String title=Booking.this.myCursor.getString(1)
```

could be setting a null value. The easiest way is to step through the code with a debugger so at least you can see which exact statement is causing the NP.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though `myCursor` is null. You'd have to look at `DBAdapter` to figure out under what circumstances `DBAdapter.getSpinnerData()` could return null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that **myCursor is NULL**.

You should **define a Constructor** in which you initialize the fields, you are later using.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by defining a constructor? 
Already declared public TextView txtArrival; at the top of my Booking.java